# What are these lines on my checkboxlist?

Tags: css, asp.net

I am using a checkboxlist and on each list item there appears to be some kind of line through the checkbox and under the text. I have tried telling it no border, but that did nothing. I am not sure what else it would be besides a border. It only happens when I have it in a cell of a table. What property or CSS could help me remove this?

[image]

```
<td style="border: none; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle;" class="grid_1";>
                    <h6>Regions:</h6>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkbxliRegions" TextAlign="Right" runat="server" Font-Size="Small">

                <asp:ListItem>AMER</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>APAC</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>EMEA</asp:ListItem>


            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>
```

When inspecting the elements in a browser it looks like the checkboxlist makes its own table and that might be what is causing this. I don't know how to fix it though.
[image]

Comment: Might be the border of the outter TR element? Go to chrome, open Dev Tools and inspect the style of the element.

Comment: can you share a more complete code without the **asp** ? i mean the final render

Comment: @mbnx the outter TR is set to have no border and shows that way upon inspection. It seems like the checkboxlist is adding its own TRs though and that might cause it. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have added a screenshot to the post with the dev tools view in Chrome. It looks like the checkboxlist is making its own table.

Comment: try removing border from tr and td, maybe it will solve the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's what I had already done, but the checkboxlist makes its own separate table within the cell with its own tr and td that I can't access directly.

Comment: yes but you can add CSS to remove border, something like that **tr,td {border:none!important;}**

Comment: @TemaniAfif But that will take it away for all tr and td. I only want it gone for these specifics ones and still need it in other instances.

Comment: yes so you have to add the id of the table ... you can see it in the screenshot (it containes **chkbxliRegions**). like that it will only apply to this one.

Comment: @TemaniAfif So I added  table#ContentPlaceHolder1_chkbxliRegions {border:none!important;} and the border is still there. How can I tell it to do that for all tr and td within that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing td and tr border by adding this CSS :

```
#ContentPlaceHolder1_chkbxliRegions tr,
#ContentPlaceHolder1_chkbxliRegions td {border:none!important;}
```